# Android ListView Repeats First Item and Does Not Update Automatically

Tags: java, android, listview

Hello I am new to android and java and currently trying to implement a ListView in my application.  My problem now is the there are two items coming from my datasource but for some reason the first item repeats twice.

This is my CursorAdapter:

```
package com.xxxxxx.eventmanager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by djoks on 15/03/2016.
 */
public class EventCursorAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public EventCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, flags);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_events, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        JSONObject dump = new JSONObject();

        try {
            dump = new JSONObject(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dump")));

            Typeface Anton = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/Anton.ttf");
            TextView dateDayView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateDay);
            dateDayView.setTypeface(Anton);
            dateDayView.setText(dump.getJSONObject("date_parts").getString("date"));

            TextView dateMonthView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateMonth);
            dateMonthView.setTypeface(Anton);
            dateMonthView.setText(dump.getJSONObject("date_parts").getString("month"));

            TextView dateEventTitleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.eventTitle);
            dateEventTitleView.setText(dump.getString("name"));

            TextView noAvailableTicketsView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noAvailableTickets);
            noAvailableTicketsView.setText("Available Tickets " + dump.getString("no_of_available_tickets"));

            TextView salesEndDateView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.salesEndDate);
            salesEndDateView.setText("Sales End Date: " + dump.getString("sales_end_date"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the XML template for my ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/layoutPadding"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/dateDay"
            android:capitalize="characters"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dateDay"
            android:id="@+id/dateMonth"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/eventTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateDay"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/salesEndDate"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateMonth"
            android:layout_below="@+id/eventTitle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/noAvailableTickets"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateMonth"
            android:layout_below="@+id/salesEndDate"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in my MainActivity.java onCreate method I have the following code:

```
mUpdater = new UpdaterModel(getApplicationContext());

        // mUpdater.open();
        Cursor c = mUpdater.getEventCursor();
        EventCursorAdapter adapter = new EventCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.list_events, c, 0 );
        // mUpdater.close();

        ListView eventListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.eventListView);
        eventListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now not only does the first item repeat twice but the ListView does not automatically update when the datasource is updated.

This is my **activity_main.xml** where I have the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/mainActivityLayout"
    tools:context="com.xxxxxx.eventmanager.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/eventListView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarContainer" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <!--<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toast Events Data"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eventListView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fab"
        android:onClick="logEventsTask"/>-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update.

Comment: Alright thank you, will try that, will that also help fix the repeating problem?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure. I cannot find something wrong in your code, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @user3718908 can you post the xml where you have declared listview

Comment: Alright, have done that.

Comment: @mad_many Tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged and it still doesn't update automatically either.

Comment: Does the database connection need to be constantly open for that to work? Coz I have an IntentService running in the background that opens and closes the connection each time it wants to execute a task.

Comment: Any resolution on repeating first item?